# GetPrivateProfileSectionNames always returns 0

Tags: c++, winapi

GetPrivateProfileSectionNames always returns 0, even when the file is a valid ini file.
What can be the reason?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide us with some code?

Comment: I think the question is too general. What are the values of the parameters you're sending to the function?

Comment: Please note, GetPrivateProfileSectionNames requires full paths as filename. What is the error code (GetLastError())?

Answer (score 0):

OK. The problem was with insufficient permission.
Thank you all.